# Finding phone number in a txt file Python

Tags: python, file, find

I have a `.txt` file that contains data about a company. I want to create an option so that when I input a phone number it displays the whole line that is in the `.txt` file. For example:

```
 Company         Adress      Employees   Phone Nr.
Venganese| Big street, Egypt|   52     |2214124112
Monyess  | One street, Malta|   89     |2215521575
```

And if I searched for `2214124112` it would return the whole line of info about the company and only that company. This is what I came up with but it really doesn't want to search for anything.

```
    elif choice == "1":
     with open( F+'.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
         for line in searchfile:
            P = re.compile(r'^(\d{8})$', re.MULTILINE)
            K = input("Enter phone nr")
            if K in line and len(len(str(abs(K)))) == P:
                print (line)
                quit()
            else:
                print ("No matching phone nr found :(")
```

Comment: ^ and $ match start and end of line therefore you search for a line containing only eight digits, nothing else. But this is only a minor problem among the wrong placement of code in the for-loop and trying to test equality to the compiled regex (which won't work).

Comment: Option B, you could throw it into a sqlite database (in memory) and query it out, if you can read the table in as a csv.

Comment: If you don't mind switching tools, this is a task for `grep` (on a terminal): `cat myfile.txt | grep 2214124112`

Comment: @jfaccioni No reason to abuse `cat`: `grep '2214124112' myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints the line if the entered number matches the phone number in the line completely or partly:

```
phonenumber = input("Enter phone number: ")
with open('myfile.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if phonenumber in line:
           print(line)
           quit()
```

This only prints the line if the entered number matches the phone number completely:

```
import re

phonenumber = input("Enter phone number: ")

pattern = re.compile(".*\|(?P<phone_number>[0-9]*)")


with open('myfile.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        phone_number = re.search(pattern, line)
        if phone_number:
            if phone_number['phone_number'] == phonenumber:
                print(line)
                quit()
```

Comment: How can I make the code so that it searches for the specific numbers that are entered and only displays a match if all of the numbers match? For example, the user enters "2214" although these numbers partly match the numbers in the txt file they don't match completely.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a second piece of code, which only will print the line if the phone number matches completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with Python, I would recommend to use `pandas`. You read the whole text file and then query the table based on the value you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('companies.txt', sep="|", names=["Company", "Adress", "Employees", "Phone Nr."], skiprows=1)

print(data.loc[data["Phone Nr."] == 2215521575])
```

results in

```
     Company              Adress  Employees   Phone Nr.
1  Monyess     One street, Malta         89  2215521575
```

Answer (score 0):

a basic concept to know before this is that an empty string is falsy in python,
i.e. `if "": ...` will evaluate as false and that part won't happen, and ```while "": ..." will abort the while loop

```
with open( F+'.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
     line = searchfile.readline()
     while line:
         line = searchfile.readline()
         phone = line.split("|")[-1]
         wanted_number = input()
         if phone == wanted_number:
             print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` to get the line with your phone number as follows

```py
import re
#with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    #txt_contents = file.read()
txt_contents = '''
 Company         Adress      Employees   Phone Nr.
Venganese| Big street, Egypt|   52     |2214124112
Monyess  | One street, Malta|   89     |2215521575
'''
phone_number = '2214124112'
regex = re.compile(r'\n.*' + phone_number + '.*\n', re.IGNORECASE)
regex
re.search(regex, txt_contents).group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with a simple list comprehension:

```
fileinput = """
 Company         Adress      Employees   Phone Nr.
Venganese| Big street, Egypt|   52     |2214124112
Monyess  | One street, Malta|   89     |2215521575

"""

def findbynumber(data, number):
    lines = [line
             for line in data.split("\n") if line
             for parts in [line.split("|")] if len(parts) == 4 and parts[3] == number]
    return lines

print(findbynumber(fileinput, "2215521575"))
```

This yields

```
['Monyess  | One street, Malta|   89     |2215521575']
```